# Backup nova using freezer occurs some errors

Tags: backup, volume, snapshot, status, openstack-nova

The below is the execute stack. Who has meet the errors, please give some advises.

```
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming [-] 快照无效: 始发 snapshot status 必须为其中一个“available”值 (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-30537939-4a05-42e2-8502-d67aafd1017e): BadRequest: \u5feb\u7167\u65e0\u6548: \u59cb\u53d1 snapshot status \u5fc5\u987b\u4e3a\u5176\u4e2d\u4e00\u4e2a\u201cavailable\u201d\u503c (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-30537939-4a05-42e2-8502-d67aafd1017e)\u5fc5\u987b\u4e3a\u5176\u4e2d\u4e00\u4e2a\u201cavailable\u201d\u503c (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-30537939-4a05-42e2-8502-d67aafd1017e)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming Traceback (most recent call last):
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/utils/streaming.py", line 112, in run
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     super(QueuedThread, self).run()
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 765, in run
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/engine/engine.py", line 107, in backup_stream
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     manifest_path))
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/utils/streaming.py", line 69, in put_messages
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     for message in messages:
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/engine/nova/nova.py", line 302, in backup_data
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     image_temporary_snapshot_id))
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/openstack/osclients.py", line 257, in do_copy_volume
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     snapshot_id=snapshot.id)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cinderclient/v2/volumes.py", line 275, in create
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     return self._create('/volumes', body, 'volume')
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cinderclient/base.py", line 304, in _create
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     resp, body = self.api.client.post(url, body=body)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cinderclient/client.py", line 217, in post
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     return self._cs_request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cinderclient/client.py", line 205, in _cs_request
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     return self.request(url, method, **kwargs)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cinderclient/client.py", line 189, in request
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, body)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming BadRequest: \u5feb\u7167\u65e0\u6548: \u59cb\u53d1 snapshot status \u5fc5\u987b\u4e3a\u5176\u4e2d\u4e00\u4e2a\u201cavailable\u201d\u503c (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-30537939-4a05-42e2-8502-d67aafd1017e)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming 
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming [-] Forced stop: Exception: Forced stop
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming Traceback (most recent call last):
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/utils/streaming.py", line 112, in run
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     super(QueuedThread, self).run()
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 765, in run
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/storage/fslike.py", line 52, in write_backup
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     for message in rich_queue.get_messages():
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/utils/streaming.py", line 90, in get_messages
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     self.check_stop()
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/utils/streaming.py", line 66, in check_stop
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming     raise Exception("Forced stop")
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming Exception: Forced stop
 ERROR freezer.utils.streaming 
 ERROR freezer.main [-] 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128): UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
 ERROR freezer.main Traceback (most recent call last):
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/main.py", line 270, in main
 ERROR freezer.main     freezer_main(backup_args)
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/main.py", line 137, in freezer_main
 ERROR freezer.main     return run_job(backup_args, storage)
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/main.py", line 150, in run_job
 ERROR freezer.main     response = freezer_job.execute()
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/job.py", line 200, in execute
 ERROR freezer.main     backup_level = self.backup(app_mode)
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/job.py", line 326, in backup
 ERROR freezer.main     restart_always_level=self.conf.restart_always_level)
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/engine/engine.py", line 183, in backup
 ERROR freezer.main     got_exception = (handle_except_queue(read_except_queue) or
 ERROR freezer.main   File "/root/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freezer/engine/engine.py", line 177, in handle_except_queue
 ERROR freezer.main     LOG.critical('Engine error: {0}'.format(e))
 ERROR freezer.main UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The errors occurs on the background that using freezer to backup the nova instance.But in the process, it orrurs wrong.

supplement:

In the auto process of using freezer to backup nova, the snapshot of nova and the snapshot of volume are generated.But the size of the snapshot of nova is 0.

Comment: Ok. I have followed your advises and modified the code format (Actually, it is the first time I ask a question in this site...).

Comment: Great – now let's hope an expert on OpenStack Nova can answer your question. (I am personally not familiar with this technology.)

Comment: Some log record are not founded in the source code. And I don't know why chinese words are occured in the log.